# AJAX sends null values

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Register form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'api.register', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'register_form']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="inputer">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input id="register_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your full name">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--.form-group-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="inputer">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input id="register_email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email address">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--.form-group-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="inputer">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input id="register_pass" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--.form-group-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="inputer">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
                <input id="register_confirm" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password again">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--.form-group-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> I have read and agree to the term of use.
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-buttons clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-white pull-left show-pane-login">Cancel</button>
        <button id="register_submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Sign Up</button>
    </div>
    <!--.form-buttons-->
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

JS:

```
        $("#register_form").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $('#register_submit').click(function()
        {
            var address = $('#register_form').attr('action');
            var method = $('#register_form').attr('method');
            var user_name = $('#register_name').val();
            var mail = $('#register_email').val();
            var pass = $('#register_pass').val();
            var pass_confirm = $('#register_confirm').val();
            var name = $("input[name=_token]").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: address,
                type: method,
                data:
                    {
                        name: user_name,
                        email: mail,
                        password: pass,
                        password_confirm : pass_confirm,
                        _token: name
                    },
                success:function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
                error:function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                },
            });
        });
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/processregister', ['as' => 'api.register', 'uses' => 'AuthController@register']);
```

Register function:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->name;
    }
```

At **webportal.dev/processregister it gives blank page**. It means request parameters sends remains null. Where I am going wrong?

(Maybe conflicts? There is also a login form on same page but it is submitted by seperate function and that login form works correctly.)

Comment: Accessing `webportal.dev/processregister` shows nothing because you pass nothing in request?

Comment: After form submission it automatically redirects me to /processregister.

Comment: Add `return false` to prevent default action of a form.

Comment: remove action from form tag and use `event.preventDefault()` in button click event and remove submit type in button

Comment: @u_mulder tried that and not working up. I have also made a login form using same stuff and that's completely working.

Comment: Change your action to `action="/processregister"` and replace the token input with `{!! csrf_field() !!}`. I just copy pasted your whole code and it works as intended. I don't see issues.

Comment: @Sandeesh what the hell...Now it is working by changing action as you said. I was basically using collective html so it was automatically inserting csrf field. I had set `"route"=>"api.register"` I replaced it with raw html and` action='"/processregister"`. And at Route I had named it `"as" => "api.register"`.
But why is it not working with collective ?

Comment: When you're sharing code for help, do not share what's generated. Always share what use in the view. How are we supposed to know you used html collective package and route to create the form? As for why it wasn't working before, we can't say that without checking your registered routes with their names and how you create the form. Either way this is resolved.

Comment: @user6803164 this is weird. The only thing i can tell you is your views might've been cached and thus leading to the issue. Glad you resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

It's due to a very common mistake in Submit button.

A button `<button>` with `type=submit` will submit the form by default, unless you stop the default behavior via `event.preventDefault()` in your `$('#register_submit').click()` function. The default behavior runs before your AJAX call is responded and forwarded to the URL in `action` attribute specified in `<form>` tag (i.e. http://webportal.dev/processregister)

In your case, you can also change the type of the button to `button` to avoid this form submission behavior.

Comment: made the changes still it sends null.. :(

Comment: You need more debugs via `console.log()` and make sure the request & response are checked in Network panel in Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `type="submit"` in this line:

```
<button id="register_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Sign Up</button>
```

Also be sure that your ajax code is really called.

Comment: made the changes still it sends null.. :(

Comment: put console.log("abc"); just before ajax call to be sure that it is executed.

Comment: yep console is positive and the vars declared are also being correctly stored.

Comment: do you see ajax call and also parameters on network tab of chrome inspector?

Comment: yep in network tab-> processregister->headers->form data I can see the values are set.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments the issue was due to your view being cached. Since i was able to run the exact same code to generate the result intended. Next time try to run `php artisan view:clear` to clear the cached views as the first step in debugging view errors. Also always post the code used when seeking help and not the code being generated.

Another tip is to assign names instead of id to the form inputs and then serialize the form data in the ajax request. You save all the work of fetching the value of each input by it's id and then using it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not moving all your code inside your `.submit` function, and just add `return false;` at the end?

```
$("#register_form").submit(function(e) {
    var address = $('#register_form').attr('action');
    var method = $('#register_form').attr('method');
    var user_name = $('#register_name').val();
    var mail = $('#register_email').val();
    var pass = $('#register_pass').val();
    var pass_confirm = $('#register_confirm').val();
    var name = $("input[name=_token]").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: address,
        type: method,
        data:
            {
                name: user_name,
                email: mail,
                password: pass,
                password_confirm : pass_confirm,
                _token: name
            },
        success:function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
        error:function(response) {
            alert(response);
        },
    });

    return false;
});
```

Please then watch what happens with your ajax request in the Developer Tools (F12) > Network tab. Perhaps there is an error on the server side.